# How to create a tron wallet with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, api, blockchain, cryptocurrency, tron

I want to create a TRON web wallet but I am a complete noob.
My first question is how do I generate addresses offline and with a private master key or with a mnemonic seed.
The second question is how can I query the balance of all addresses generated by me with a single request to TronGrid?

Comment: CHeck https://developers.tron.network/docs/trongridjs.

Comment: I checked but I did not found anything for generating a mnemonic seed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have `TronWeb` installed.

You can do `TronWeb.createAccount()` to generate an address and save the output, [example from docs](https://developers.tron.network/reference#createaccount).

You may need to check balance of address one by one by posting to TronGrid, `https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/getaccount`, [example from docs](https://developers.tron.network/reference#walletgetaccount)

Comment: that's not an option. it requires me to have an external wallet. I don't need one, instead i want nodejs to be the manager of crypto adresses that is a wallet

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1 - npm install ton web and crypto lib**

```
const TronWeb = require('tronweb');
var crypto = require('crypto');
```

**Step 2 - Generate random private key and use the private key to create tronweb account**

```
var privateKey = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
console.log("Private Key", privateKey);

const HttpProvider = TronWeb.providers.HttpProvider;
const fullNode = new HttpProvider("https://api.trongrid.io");
const solidityNode = new HttpProvider("https://api.trongrid.io");
const eventServer = new HttpProvider("https://api.trongrid.io");
const tronWeb = new TronWeb(fullNode,solidityNode,eventServer,privateKey);

const wallet = await tronWeb.createAccount();
console.log(wallet);
```

**Step 3 - result**

```
{
privateKey: 'D526E0AB73B3552F0B0FB85838DB364D90C1CAC4BC76294373FABA83C04914DD',
publicKey: '04CA86DEFC9C8828DB52DBF6DD44872DE863AC53126B9D49260AB677CB0B9A18BC0276A58DAC04928AEDDAC85B8CFDFA8A8536832735BD8C5E0AE84BE2E505D83F',
  address: {
    base58: 'TVFFvcUB6CWLFh45n28Ve1XRmu1NYSKS34',
    hex: '41D3737C4D6B5105692B01409738D29CD796876602'
  }
}
```

Generate a random mnemonic (total number 12) and using TRON path "m/44'/195'" by default, return the 0th account address and private key

```
tronWeb.createRandom()
{
  "mnemonic": {
    "phrase": "chimney cloth deny claim play rude love dose apart shove rack stone",
    "path": "m/44'/195'/0'/0/0",
    "locale": "en"
  },
  "privateKey": "0x79092289f3bfde55f079202e3642b2c4ba071d5f0b85d65b1919c8724e94848c",
  "publicKey": "0x0421c47d627bc2d856760dda17b42b726b4bc8f5def76aed0cbcd71566d0ffedfc3904c9c854854a5019b8373d2aed0c6b96ff5f3be07722403088742b0949a6c9",
  "address": "TEFAyPnainfiAJBuhExfMLJeHHxD2DZJmF",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1-** install tronweb npm package:

```
npm i tronweb
```

**2-** use this example:

```
// create tronweb client
const TronWeb = require('tronweb');
const fullNode = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';
const solidityNode = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';
const eventServer = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';
const privateKey = 'xxx';
const tronWeb = new TronWeb(fullNode,solidityNode,eventServer,privateKey);

// create new account
const account = tronWeb.createAccount();

//IMPORTANT: don't forget to encrypt account private key before store
//and don't forget clear variable[memory!] 
//account result example::
//{ address: {
//  base58: "TPbBpRXnt6ztse8XkCLiJstZyqQZvxW2sx", 
//hex: "4195679F3AAF5211991781D49B30525DDDFE9A18DE"}
//privateKey: "08089C24EC3BAEB34254DDF5297CF8FBB8E031496FF67B4EFACA738FF9EBD455"
//publicKey:  "04EE63599802B5D31A29C95CC7DF04F427E8F0A124BED9333F3A80404ACFC3127659C540D0162DEDB81AC5F74B2DEB4962656EFE112B252E54AC3BA1207CD1FB10" }
```

for more info visit tronweb documentation:
[tronweb documentation](https://developers.tron.network/reference/createaccount)

> for other programming languages and platforms use
> [TRON FULL NODE API](https://developers.tron.network/reference/account-createaccount)
>
> for encrypt the private key visit this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953606/1862306)