# How to clear buffers in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, buffer

I am implementing encryption/decryption of logs, and came across a [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53573115) on another SO question that used the node crypto library. In the code, its mentioned that the buffers storing the plaintext and cipher key need to be cleared after the encryption / decryption process so that it doesn't "linger in the memory".

I understand this concept, but how does one clear a buffer? I've tried searching on SO and the official node documentation for buffer object, but I couldn't find much. So far, I've considered: setting the variable to null trigger Node's garbage collection, or using `Buffer.fill()`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `Buffer.fill()` is how you clear a buffer if you're using an actual Buffer object.  Setting the variable to `null` will trigger garbage collection (if nobody else has a reference to it), but that does still allow the data to sit in memory until that memory is reused which is what the sample code is trying to avoid.

Comment: Oh so after returning the buffer object, I just have to call `Buffer.fill()` and the sensitive data will be replaced with the random character instead, thereby "clearing" it?

Comment: No.  Did you look at the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_fill_value_offset_end_encoding) for `buffer.fill()`?  It fills the buffer with a character of your choosing (many developers choose `0`), overwriting prior data.

Comment: Yep, I think I also meant what you just said, but just phrased poorly ;-; In essence, overwrite the buffer's previous data with a random character like 0 using `fill(0)` right?

Comment: Yes, that would be it.  More detailed help would require seeing the actual code.